# MapInfo / MapXtreme is it possible to get the Features from a Table

Tags: c#, mapinfo, features

I'm trying to get the Features from a table with MapXtreme 7.0.0. I use winforms with the MapControl from MapInfo.

Is it possible to get all the Features from a table?

Something like: `table.GetFeature();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an `MIDataReader` on the table and then iterate through it.

```
Table exampleTable = catalog.OpenTable(exampleTableName, "ExampleTable");
MIDataReader tableReader = exampleTable.ExecuteReader();
foreach (Feature ftr in tableReader)
{
//do stuff
}
```